# I have node.js c ++, java, python compiler. in some cases it returns node.js error without any compiler error

Tags: java, node.js, child-process

I have node.js c ++, java, python compiler. in some cases it returns node.js error without any compiler error:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s9qoi.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/czNSf.png)

works on the base and again I did not know the error is related to **progress.kill** I guess
This is a problem for some of the restaurants where he worked.

I have an exec function in docker, linux, node.Js

Comment: Don't spam tags. Don't tag irrelevant languages. *Do* tag the language you actually program in. And don't post images of text. Please take some time to refresh [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take the SO [tour], read [ask], as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: i am not allowed to put a picture other than text . i am not allowed to put a picture other than text. i have c ++, python, java, go, mono c # all. @Someprogrammerdude

Comment: Don't use pictures at all. Copy and paste your code into the question directly (with the appropriate formatting)

Comment: Code in stackoverflow questions/answers should NEVER be in images.  From images, it can't be copied and pasted into answers.  It can't be indexed for search.  It can't be easily read on mobile or by the visually impaired.  And, of selfish interested to you, it doesn't attract people to work on your question.